# How to allow Flutter to get a value that it stored in a firebase server or any server?

Tags: http, https, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Right now I am using an http 0.11.3+16 and I am able to add a true value to an item on the site using the following function:

```
    if (newAcceptStatus) {
  response = await http.put('https://example.com/example1/${selectedOrder.id}/example2/${_authenticatedUser.id}.json?auth=${_authenticatedUser.token}',
      body: json.encode(true));
```

this function is only called when the admin is logged in and the admin is the only one that can change the status of the Boolean, so the value is stored under the admins id and token. so I tried the following to help show if the item was changed by the admin to the user but i keep getting that the value is null when i decode the response with the following function:

> ```
>   Future<Null> checkAccept() async{
>     http.Response response;
>     response = await http.get('https://example.com/example1/${selectedOrder.id}/example2/(admin id goes here).json?auth=${_authenticatedUser.token}');
>     accepted = json.decode(response.body);
> }
> ```

not sure what i am doing wrong. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: the concept is as follows a user post an order for an item and there is a section with the orders the user has and then the admin sees this product and is able to accept or decline it, and when that happens i would like the user to be able to see that the order was accepted or declined. that's why i need it to retrieve the data back. thinking about it now i might want to not save it under the admins id or any id for that matter.

Comment: Could you check on the firebase console if the problem is saving or retrieving? Also, print your variables to see if their values are really what you expect (the ones composing the url, for instance).

Comment: @LuanNico the server is receiving and saving, when i retrieve it and assign the body to a variable. I print that variable and it shows up as null

Comment: So things to try : print the URL you are getting to see if it actually is like you believe, test to GET it in the browser or postman, see if it returns null or not. Check if the problem is in the url or the form it is being fetch by dart.

Comment: @LuanNico thanks for that help, figured out that the list of items i was getting the value from was not the right one which is why it was empty and null!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the wrong list of items which were very similar, thus giving me an empty list